# Adding elements from a ListBox to a List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

I have a ListBox with Integers in it that gets them from a SQL database. Now I wanted to put these elements into a List when they get selected but somehow it won't work. Here is the code:

```
List<Int32>typeElements = new List<Int32>();

if(form1.listBox.SelectedIndex != -1)   
{
    foreach (var selectedItem in form1.listBox.SelectedItems)
    {
        typeElements.Add(selectedItem);
    }
}
```

He tells me he can't convert object to int and that the method has some invalid arguments. How to handle that?

Comment: `typeElements.Add((int)selectedItem);` If you sure that the `selectedItem` is of type `int`.

Comment: Now I get an InvalidCastException even if I change that to Int32

Comment: Do you read the second part of comment?

Comment: Yes I did. Maybe it hast something to do with the SQL Database but there it is an Int

Comment: What does the debugger say the type of `selectedItem` is?

Comment: System.Data.DataRowView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ListBox.SelectedItems is a collection of objects. You can't simply take an element from this collection and add it to a typed list of integers. 
You need a conversion

```
typeElements.Add(Convert.ToInt32(selectedItem));
```

If you want to use Linq and the IEnumerable extensions then you could write your loop in one line

```
// List<Int32>typeElements = new List<Int32>();
List<Int32> typeElements = form1.listBox.Items.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

**EDIT:**
Following your comment then you need to extract the Integer element from the DataRowView

```
DataRow row = (selectedItem as DataRowView).Row;
typeElements.Add(row.Field<int>("NameOfYourDataBaseIntegerField"));
```

Comment: The first one tells me: an object from type System.Data.DataRowView can't be converted to a System.IConvertible and the second one gives me another invalidCastException

Comment: Then you add items to the ListBox using a DataSource. This means that every element is a DataRowView and we need to know the name of the field that contains the integer to extract it from the DataRowView

Comment: So I need to put them in a Data Table or something? How do I do that from the ListBox when a user chooses elements?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this (using System.Linq):**

`OfType()` is an extension method, so you need to use `System.Linq`

```
List<Int32> selectedFields = new List<Int32>();
selectedFields.AddRange(listbox.CheckedItems.OfType<Int32>());
```

Or just do it in one line:

```
List<Int32> selectedFields = listbox.CheckedItems.OfType<Int32>().ToList();
```

Comment: He can't find a definition for "ToList()"

Comment: What is chkDFMFieldList?